# Google Play Console Вопрос с налогами А так же Аккаунт продавца

Tags: unity3d, google-play-console

Здраствуйте я очень обеспокоен темой налогов. Создал свое приложение и хочу опубликовывать в `Google Play`, но необходимо создать аккаунт продавца и там выбрать систему налогов
Вопросы:

1. если игра не будет приносить мне доход, налог будет копиться?
2. 20% на налог это сам `Google` оплатит за меня?
3. Когда я зарегистрировал аккаунт разработчика на меня зарегистрировали налоги?
4. Как можно не платить налоги? может есть какое-то условие?
   Много раз видел что дети публикуют свои игры но вот вопрос как они справились с 4 вопросами
   и много раз разработчикам игра не приносила прибыль

извиняюсь что объяснил вопрос не понятно. Объяснил как смог

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Насколько я помню, `Google Play` единоразового требует покупку аккаунта разработчика (достаточно дешево) после чего больше с Вас ничего не требует

Налог Google лучше назвать все-таки **комиссией** самого Google. С реальными налогами в государство он никак не связан

Гугл будет забирать деньги только с дохода. Никаких налогов не копится

Пример:

Возьмем таблицу доходов, общей выручки и доход после вычета налогов `Google` (возьмем 20%)

```
Месяц:  | Сумма | После вычета налогов
1       | 0     |  0
2       | 0     |  0
3       | 10    |  8
```

То, есть, Вы получили, предположим 10 долларов и у Вас забрали 2 доллара в виде налога

Бездоходность до этого не учитывается. Считайте, что налог уже был взят с суммы равной 0

В общем и целом ответы на Ваши вопросы

1. Нет, налоги вычитаются только с площадки `Google Play`. В случае, если Ваше приложение бездоходное, то налог вычитается с 0
2. Нет, по закону, Вы должны уже будете платить уже настоящий налог государству (Выручка - налог от гугла)/(налоговую ставку)
3. Вы отдаете свой процент Google, никакие налоги в государство не платятся
4. Пишите в Google. Сомневаюсь, что кто-то не платит их налог

Answer (score 1):

Немного дополню уже данный ответ:

1. Нет дохода - нет комиссий
2. 20% - это НДС. Его вы оплачиваете самостоятельно. Google в России не платит этот налог за разработчика. Вот здесь подробнее: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138000?hl=ru#zippy=%2C%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B
3. Google забирает свою комиссию 15% или 30% в зависимости от того, какая у вас. Предположим, у вас она 15%. (Пониженную комиссию Google ввёл относительно недавно).
4. Таким образом, Google перечислит вам на счёт сумму равную ("Выручка" - 15% комиссия). При продажах на 10 долларов на выходе получим 8,5 долларов. С этой суммы вы будете должны самостоятельно заплатить НДС и налог на прибыль.